# stop a player when collides with tiles in android

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to make  a simple game on the framework badlogicgames by mario zechner. I am simply trying to place some tiles say..trees, bushes etc and want my player to stop when it passes thru them ... to give a good effect.. I tried many alternatives..but not working...

1.) I tried to define a boolean `playerBolcked = false`; ...in collision detection loop i set it to true .. and when it is true .. i blocked the player movement ..`update()`;

2.) I tried to store the position of player before checking collision..if player collides with tile...
then i again set the position back... it too didn't work ...

My detection code is like this ...

```
private void checkTreeCollisions() {
        int len = trees.size();
        float x = allen.position.x;
        float y =allen.position.y;



     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                Tree tree = trees.get(i);

                    if (OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(allen.bounds, tree.bounds)) {

                            // this is not working
                        allen.position.set(x, y);


                        break;

                }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me a  good way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

In your collision detection, check first if it collided horizontally meaning in x-axis, then put player's velocity on x to zero. Then check vertically, if player collides on y-axis, put its y velocity to zero.

[This](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-tutorial-part-4-collision-detection/) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, in your code you are saving the position of the player and checking the collision at the same time. What you need to do is moving the player after saving his/her position and before checking for collisions:

```
private void checkTreeCollisions() {
    int len = trees.size();
    //Save your player position here
    float x = allen.position.x;
    float y =allen.position.y;

    //Move your player move code here, so he moves, then checks collitions

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         Tree tree = trees.get(i);

         if (OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(allen.bounds, tree.bounds)) {

             //If collision, then set the player to his/her previous position
             allen.position.set(x, y);
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

You can divide the movement for x and y axis with this same logic and you will be able to "slide" in the objects sides which looks much better then just stopping.